# YII2 sef urls construction

Tags: php, url, yii2, sef

I have catalogue with products. Urls for products looks like this `domain.com/adv?id=14792`.
I want to beautify urls like this `domain.com/adv/14792`.

In web.php I tried to like this

```
'urlManager' => [
 'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
 'showScriptName' => false,
 'enableStrictParsing' => true,
 'rules' => [
  'adv/<id:\d+>' => 'site/adv',
  '<alias:[\w-]+>' => 'site/<alias>',
 ],
],
```

and there is no result.

I tried another variant in rules block:

```
'rules' => [
  'adv/<id:\d+>' => 'adv',
  '<alias:[\w-]+>' => 'site/<alias>',
 ],
```

and urls start to look like I want. But on this link I get 404 page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by myself. This is my urlmanager module now:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
      'adv/<id:\d+>' => 'site/adv',
      '<alias:[\w-]+>' => 'site/<alias>',
      '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ],
```

this construction build url from `https://example.com/adv?id=123456` to `https://example.com/adv/123456`.
In view link build with

```
Html::a($insideEl,Url::to(['adv','id' => $ladvert->id]))
```

and in siteController action is

```
actionAdv($id)
```

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Please use action with adv so that it work.

```
    'rules' => [
  'adv/<id:\d+>' => 'adv/<add some action here>',
  '<alias:[\w-]+>' => 'site/<alias>',
 ],
```